How to fetch Entry Forms (within Customize tab) in NetSuite using REST APIs or Restlets?
I've encountered a hurdle where I need to retrieve the 'Entry Form' (shown in UI within Customize tab) of type CRM using either REST API or RestLets. My main challenge is locating the record_type corresponding to the Entry Forms. Once I know the record_type of these forms, I can use the services/record/v1/<record_type>  REST API, or a SuiteScript RestLet's 'N/record' module to fetch these forms.
I have tried looking for the answer almost everywhere, but I didn't see even this question anywhere else. It seems that not many people work with the Entry Forms using apis.

Are you trying to retrieve a list of entry forms to provide choices of some sort? The entry form list is not exposed via the REST API

hi,  yes, I need to retrieve the Entry Forms, in my case I am interested in those of type CRM -> Solution. If not exposed by Rest APIs, is there a way to fetch them using RestLets (SuiteScript) ?

If you need details you can get them via SDF but whether that is practical depends on what you are trying to do. There are ways to get lists of forms via scripts but not details.
